# WPF InkCanvas inherit class

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

I want to create an custom InkCanvas Adorner and found the logic behind:

> You can re-use the existing lasso functionality of the **InkCanvasEditingMode.Select** mode. Then, in the SelectionChanged event, you can get a reference to the selected strokes (and/or elements). Now clear the selection (to get rid of the standard adorner) and then bring up your custom adorner.

How can i inherit the InkCanvas class with the editing mode in my own class and get access to the Events?

```
class myInkCanvasClass : InkCanvas ?
{
    base class constructor call ?
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to inherit the InkCanvas Class to my CustomInkCanvas Class and get the EventListener of SelectionChanged:

```
public class CustomInkCanvas : InkCanvas
{
    //variables 

    //constructor
    public CustomInkCanvas()
    {
       //...
    }

    override protected void OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs e) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selection Changed");
    }
}
```

So if i change a Selection i get noticed.

Answer (score 1):

```
[DebuggerDisplay("[{Scene}]Strokes:{Strokes.Count}, Children:{Children.Count}")]
public class InkCanvas_Sandeep : InkCanvas
{
    public int PagId = -1;
    public InkCanvas_Sandeep()
    {
        DefaultDrawingAttributes.Color = Colors.Red;
        DefaultDrawingAttributes.FitToCurve = true;
        DefaultDrawingAttributes.Height = 2;
        DefaultDrawingAttributes.Width = 2;
        DefaultDrawingAttributes.IgnorePressure = false;
        DefaultDrawingAttributes.IsHighlighter = false;
        DefaultDrawingAttributes.StylusTip = System.Windows.Ink.StylusTip.Ellipse;
        DefaultDrawingAttributes.StylusTipTransform = Matrix.Identity;
        HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
    }
}
public void createMultipleInstances()
{
    InkCanvas_Sandeep canvas new InkCanvas_Sandeep();
    canvas.PagId = ++PageDetails.PageId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to inherit from `InkCanvas`, `SelectionChanged` is a public event on `InkCanvas` so you can just add a handler to it. Also the `EditingMode` is a public property that you can set on an instance of `InkCanvas` as well. So to add the handler to `SelectionChanged` and toggle the `EditingMode` between `Ink` and `Select` you can just use the public API of an `InkCanvas` instance.

Basic example:

```
inkCanvas.SelectionChanged += InkCanvas_SelectionChanged;
inkCanvas.EditingMode = InkCanvasEditingMode.Select;
```

Comment: I want to remove the original InkCanvas - Select - Adorner when the SelectionChanged Event is fired and replace it with a custom Adorner. So i thougth, i have to inherit the InkCanvas Class and call the custom Adorner on a SelectionChanged Event. How would i accomblish this?